# Shuffle youtube IDs

Tags: php, json, youtube-api, shuffle

am new to php and I was wondering how I could retrieve shuffled YouTube IDs..
Here is what I mean..

```
$playlist_id = "PLB9DAD6B9EDAEE7BC";

$cont = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/'.$playlist_id.'/?v=2&alt=json&feature=plcp'));
$feed = $cont->feed->entry;

if(count($feed)) {
    foreach($feed as $item) {
        $title = $item->title->{'$t'};
        $desc = $item->{'media$group'}->{'media$description'}->{'$t'};  
        $id = $item->{'media$group'}->{'yt$videoid'}->{'$t'};
    }
}
```

This basically fetches the id, title and description from the playlist, how can I shuffle the `$id` to give me unique unrepeated values so that I can later on use it here?

`<iframe ... src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?= $id ?>" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

My goal is to refresh the page to get a new video each time I visit it and reset itself when it's over (or just continue picking unique values)

Thank you in advance, a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all the feed videos in an array and then use array_rand to get a random entry of the array.

See http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-rand.php for function reference.
Be aware that array_rand return a single key when used with default settings but it will deliver an array of keys if you choose to select more then a single random entry.

**EDIT: Added cookie so the video is REAL random-unique**

Code snippet:

```
$playlist_id = "PLB9DAD6B9EDAEE7BC";

$cont = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/'.$playlist_id.'/?v=2&alt=json&feature=plcp'));
$feed = $cont->feed->entry;

$youtubeVideos = array();

if(count($feed))
{
  foreach($feed as $item)
  {
    // build video array
    $video = array();
    $video['title'] = $item->title->{'$t'};
    $video['desc'] = $item->{'media$group'}->{'media$description'}->{'$t'};
    $video['id'] = $item->{'media$group'}->{'yt$videoid'}->{'$t'};

    // push it into collection
    $youtubeVideos[$video['id']] = $video;
  }
}

$seenVideos=array();
$lastSeenVideo='';

// only get diff array if the cookies are set (= not first page view)
if(isset($_COOKIE['seen_youtube_videos']) && isset($_COOKIE['last_youtube_video']))
{
  $lastSeenVideo=$_COOKIE['last_youtube_video'];

  $seenVideos=unserialize($_COOKIE['seen_youtube_videos']);
  $diffArr=$youtubeVideos;

  foreach($seenVideos as $vidId)
    unset($diffArr[$vidId]);

  if(count($diffArr)>0)
  {
    // set difference for searching only
    $youtubeVideos=$diffArr;
  }
  else
  {
    // if we did show all videos, reset everything
    setcookie('seen_youtube_videos', '');
    setcookie('last_youtube_video', '');
    $seenVideos = array();
  }
}

$randomizedKey = array_rand($youtubeVideos);
$randomVideo = $youtubeVideos[$randomizedKey];

do
{
  $randomizedKey = array_rand($youtubeVideos);
  $randomVideo = $youtubeVideos[$randomizedKey];
}
while($randomVideo['id'] == $lastSeenVideo);


$seenVideos[] = $randomVideo['id'];
setcookie('seen_youtube_videos', serialize($seenVideos));
setcookie('last_youtube_video', $randomVideo['id']);

// do stuff with $randomVideo
```

Comment: I tried it and it works great but the cookies do not die after the browser is closed, is using sessions better?

Comment: In general using a session is a complete odd construct and per definition of the setcookie function (see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) the cookie shall be deleted when browser closes as described: "expire: The time the cookie expires. This is a Unix timestamp so is in number of seconds since the epoch. [...] . If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes)." You can try if setting the expire param to explicit 0 helps